# Django - customize result list - add element ID

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I would like to override default Admin Panel result list (change_list_results.html) to add ID for each row in `<tr>`

Default is:

```
<tbody>
        {% for result in results %}
            {% if result.form.non_field_errors %}
                <tr><td colspan="{{ result|length }}">{{ result.form.non_field_errors }}</td></tr>
            {% endif %}
            <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">{% for item in result %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}</tr>
        {% endfor %}
 </tbody>
```

I would like to have:

```
<tbody>
        {% for result in results %}
            {% if result.form.non_field_errors %}
                <tr><td colspan="{{ result|length }}">{{ result.form.non_field_errors }}</td></tr>
            {% endif %}
            <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}" id="{{ ID }}">{% for item in result %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}</tr>
        {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

What should i put into `{{ ID }}` to get element ID?

Comment: `{{ID}}` this belongs to what? What id you need here? and for what reason?

Comment: It only a placeholder. I need this because i would like to create drag and drop function (JS) to sort items. So i need id for each TR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the 'items' context variable does not hold instance data, it's just a list with html for each column. To achieve what you need you must search for the equivalent item in the 'cl.result_list' context variable, based on the forloop counter:

```
<tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}" id="{% with i=forloop.counter0|stringformat:"s"|add:":" %}{% with items=cl.result_list|slice:i %}{{ items.0.pk }}{% endwith  %}{% endwith %}">{% for item in result %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}</tr>
```

Alternatively, if you don't like all these 'with' tags you could create a custom template to get the item from "cl.result_list" directly from the counter index.

Comment: It works! I don't know if it's optimal but it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: welcome. No it's not otpimal. Writing a custom template tag to do the las >tr.. part would be optimal

Comment: Hi. I understand. I am thinking also about overriding function which pass *results* to the template and add there pk.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess `{{ result.form.instance.id }}` judging by the fact there is a `result.form` attached to a list of `results`.

Just deductive reasoning. Let me know if it's wrong.